# react auth render different view flickering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Anything wrong with the code below? I have flickering problem, it will render userArea first before go into AdminArea.

```
render(){

        const isAdmin = this.props.role === 'admin' ? true : false

        return(
            <div>
                {isAdmin ? <AdminArea /> : <UserArea />}
                {this.logout()}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle demonstrating this? might be worth putting a `console.log(this.props.role)` into the code before the return to see if it is getting called multiple times.

Comment: `? true : false` is unnecessary part. Comparison returns `true` or `false`

Comment: @Phil do I need a fiddle? it's clearly the render method will render twice.

Comment: ok, well it wasn't clear to me why it was rendering twice without the context of a working example. I guess is that `this.props.role` starts as `null` and is not set until after the initial render. But I can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

That code looks fine. If UserArea is rendering, it’s because the “role” prop is not “admin” initially.

You can observe this by console logging the “role” prop in your render. The initial “role” prop value should help you trace down the issue.

In my experience, flickering is often be the user data isn’t loaded initially. After loading, the expected prop is there. I suspect you may have the same issue here. If this is the case, avoid flickering by setting a userLoaded prop and render this component when userLoaded is true. `userLoaded && <ThisComponent />`

Comment: I see. But what if I don't want to put any loader?

Comment: Great question, I prefer to make that check based on data that isn’t loaded to keep the store clean. For example, if the “role” prop is null or false initially, I use `role && <ThisCompenent />`. When role has a value as user or admin, the component renders. It would be cool to see if anyone else has another solution. This is how I have handled it.